# Incrementing an unsigned char array

Tags: c

I have a program that takes in an `unsigned char ctr[24]`. This is going to be used many times and I would like to have a new `ctr` for each operation. So I would need to either generate a random value each time, or I could initialize it to 0 and increment. I am after performance so generating a new value each time is probably going to be slow versus just incrementing. Is it possible to increment a unsigned char array?

`0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00`

Increment it by one...

`0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x01`

etc..

`0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x02`

Comment: You want to treat `ctr` an a `24*8` bit value?

Comment: To me this Q is unclear... what do you mean by `Is it possible to increment a unsigned char array?` Increment every element? or...?

Comment: Yes, it is possible to increment it, just like any number, and it's also faster.

Comment: @pmg yes that is correct.

Comment: You say a random value is acceptable: why not pick *one* element at random and increment that?

Comment: Is it important that it is an incrementing pattern ?

Comment: incrementing is important since this value cannot be used again.

Comment: `int n = 24; while (n-- && ++ctr[n] == 0);`

Comment: @vs123 So you can't use random beause that may give the same number twice!

Comment: If the function can be external, you can also optimize it by using your systems add-with-carry (`adc` in x86) instruction directly instead of using bithacks that your compiler may or may not recognize. You'll also get a lot better performance if you reinterpret cast the array to your systems word size.

Comment: @IanAbbott That's so nice it should be in an answer.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Or [micro optimize](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/80084/94903) with `int n = 24; while (++ctr[--n] == 0 && n);`

Comment: *I have a program that takes in a unsigned char ctr[24]. This is going to be used many times and I would like to have a new ctr for each operation.*  How about first trying a simple `unsigned long long` and timing how long it takes to wrap around before thinking you need a 192-bit counter **that's even slower**.  [The odds of you being able to use all the possible values of a 64-bit value are, umm, infinitesimal](https://www.reddit.com/r/ProgrammerTIL/comments/4tspsn/c_it_will_take_approximately_97_years_to_overflow/)

Comment: That doesn't answer the question and is off topic.

Comment: @vs123 It's called a [frame challenge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/263661/does-stack-exchange-allow-for-answers-which-question-the-validity-or-stance-of-t).  It ***is*** an answer, and it ***is*** on topic.  Have you thought about why you need a 192-bit counter managed yourself byte-by-byte when a 64-bit native `unsigned long long` provides more than enough bits?  Or did you not mean it when you posted "I am after performance"?  Because if you really cared about performance, you wouldn't use a contrived 192-bit self-managed counter when a 64-bit native one is more than sufficient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Treating `unsigned char ctr[24] = {0};` as a counter initialized to 0, the 24 elements can be treated as digits of a base `UCHAR_MAX+1` number. Based on the question, the "units" digit is to be stored in `ctr[23]`, the "base<sup>1</sup>" digit in `ctr[22]`, the "base<sup>2</sup>" digit in `ctr[21]`, etc. When a digit with value `UCHAR_MAX` is incremented it will become 0 and a "carry bit" value of 1 needs to be added to the next digit position.

```
void increment(unsigned char ctr[static 24])
{
    unsigned int pos = 24;
    while (pos-- && ++ctr[pos] == 0)
        ;
}
```

The above function increments an `unsigned char[24]` in place. It first increments `ctr[23]` and if it has wrapped around to 0, increments `ctr[22]`, and so forth until one of the digits has not wrapped around to 0, or all of the digits have wrapped around to 0.

Comment: Might take a while for `pos--` to be false. ;-)

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica I can wait. :-)

Answer (score 3):

You are vanishingly unlikely to really need to....
I mean if you just took the first 8 bytes and treated them as an uint64_t that would run a long, long, time before wrapping around.

Seems to me that some pointer casty stuff and that is job done for any likely use case.

Note that you might need to use some bytes in the middle of your 24 to ensure your memory is aligned suitably for a 64 bit access, but that is a triviality.

Comment: This is ***the*** answer - but just use an `unsigned long long`.

Comment: *"some pointer casty stuff and that is job done"* Smells like incoming strict aliasing violation.

Comment: @user694733 In C the union based approach is not UB. It still has the alignment headache.

Comment: @DanMills There's not even any need for a `union`.  Just use a `uint64_t` directly.  That's good for about a century of run-time at 3,000,000,000 increment operations per second.  I doubt the OP needs distinct values that quick for that long...

Comment: @AndrewHenle The union is to work around the type punning restrictions in the C standard, not out of any concern that incrementing a uint64_t is going to wrap any time soon.

Answer (score 1):

```
void *inc(void *buff, size_t size)
{
    unsigned char *cbuff = buff;
    for(size_t index = 0; index < size; index++)
    {
        if(cbuff[index] == 255)
        {
            cbuff[index] = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            cbuff[index]++;
            break;
        }
    }
    return buff;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> I have a program that takes in a unsigned char ctr[24]. This is going to be used many times and I would like to have a new ctr for each operation. So I would need to either generate a random value each time, or I could initialize it to 0 and increment. I am after performance so generating a new value each time is probably going to be slow versus just incrementing. Is it possible to increment a unsigned char array?

Just ***don't***.

Use a simple `unsigned long long`.  It's more than big enough.

At 3 ***billion*** increment operations per second, [it would take 97 years to roll over a 64-bit value](https://www.reddit.com/r/ProgrammerTIL/comments/4tspsn/c_it_will_take_approximately_97_years_to_overflow/).

`unsigned long long` is big enough.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this? *untested*

```
void add1_recur(unsigned char *x, int lo) {
    if (lo < 0) /* 192 bit overflow! */ exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    if (x[lo] == 255) {
        x[lo] = 0;
        add1_recur(x, lo - 1;)
    } else {
        x[lo] += 1;
    }
}

// add 1 to x; assume x[0] is high order bit
void add1_inplace(unsigned char x[static 24]) {
    add1_recur(x, 23);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand you just need a new pattern each time. Not necessarily a counter.

So would a union do?

Like:

```
typedef union
{
    uint64_t d64[3];
    unsigned char d8[24];
} ctr_t;

void p(unsigned char ca[])
{
    for (int i=0; i<24; ++i) printf("0x%02X ", ca[i]);
    puts("");
}

void change(ctr_t* ctr)
{
    // Do some change to each of the three uint64
    ++ctr->d64[0];
    --ctr->d64[1];
    ++ctr->d64[2];
}

int main(void) {
    ctr_t ctr = {{0, 0, 0xff00ff00ff}};  // Just some initialization
    p(ctr.d8);
    change(&ctr);
    p(ctr.d8);
    change(&ctr);
    p(ctr.d8);
    change(&ctr);
    p(ctr.d8);
    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0xFF 0x00 0xFF 0x00 0xFF 0x00 0x00 0x00 
0x01 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0x00 0x01 0xFF 0x00 0xFF 0x00 0x00 0x00 
0x02 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0xFE 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0x01 0x01 0xFF 0x00 0xFF 0x00 0x00 0x00 
0x03 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0xFD 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0x02 0x01 0xFF 0x00 0xFF 0x00 0x00 0x00
```